# Calculating Percent Change in Soliidity

Tags: solidity, remix

So I'm using Remix and have the following code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract Negs {

  event Print(string _name, uint _value);

  function Test() {
    var startValue = 1000;
    var endValue = 800;
    Print ("Change1 - ", endValue / startValue);
    Print ("Change2 - ", 10*endValue / startValue);
    Print ("Change3 - ", 100*endValue / startValue);
    Print ("Change4 - ", 1000*endValue / startValue);
  }

}
```

And then looking at the events in the little box to the right once starting Test, I get the following values:

- Change 1 - 0
- Change 2 - 8
- Change 3 - 14
- Change 4 - 13

I know that Change 1 should be zero as there's no decimals, got that..but what about the other ones?  Why wouldn't Change3 be 80 and change4 800?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Solidity `var` is determining the type at first assignment and takes whatever fits. Read the warning [here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#type-deduction). Therefore your code translates into:

```
uint16 startValue = 1000;
uint16 endValue = 800;
```

Then, your calculation overflows as it translates into:

```
(100*800 % (2**16)) / 1000 = 14
```

and

```
(1000*800 % (2**16))/1000 = 13
```

Beware of `var` and assign it a type that you know will be fine at runtime! Also, use the [`SafeMath` library](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/SafeMath.sol) whenever you need something decently secure+safe.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Sebastian, I had no idea var was something to avoid in solidity